ESP8266 Web Server SPIFFS
I want to create a automatic time controlled servo using built in RTC in ESP8266. whenever i write data to SPIFFS, it does not make any changes on my if condition for the movement of servo.
This is the codes that I'm using. Whenever I'm using "== 'minute1'" it always says that "warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]. I just want to fetch the data from SPIFFS and place it on if condition to set the time and make the servo move on the specific time I submit from webserver.

void loop() {
  
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  struct tm* p_tm = localtime(&now);

  String minute1 = read_file(SPIFFS, "/input_string.txt");
  Serial.print("Minute1: ");
  Serial.println(minute1);
  
  int minute2 = read_file(SPIFFS, "/input_int.txt").toInt();
  Serial.print("Minute2: ");
  Serial.println(minute2);
  
  float minute3= read_file(SPIFFS, "/input_float.txt").toFloat();
  Serial.print("Minute3: ");
  Serial.println(minute3);
  
  int val;
  int val2;

   if( (p_tm->tm_hour == 13) && (p_tm->tm_min == 'minute1') && (p_tm->tm_sec == 00)){
      val = 0;
      servo1.write(val);
  }

  else if( (p_tm->tm_hour == 13) && (p_tm->tm_min == 'minute2') && (p_tm->tm_sec == 05)){
      val = 180;
      servo1.write(val);
  }

  if( ((p_tm->tm_hour) == 'hour') && (p_tm->tm_min == 'minute3') && (p_tm->tm_sec == 15)){
      val2 = 0;
    servo1.write(val2);
    delay(20);
  }
  else if( (p_tm->tm_hour == 13) && (p_tm->tm_min == 18) && (p_tm->tm_sec == 20)){
      val2 = 180;
    servo1.write(val2);
    delay(20);
  }

  Serial.print(p_tm->tm_hour);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.print(p_tm->tm_min);
  Serial.print(":");
  Serial.println(p_tm->tm_sec);

  
  delay(1000);
}

Please help me. this is my first time to develop this esp8266 with SPIFFS
